# Obtener último registro de cada producto en la tabla kardex

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, postgresql

Hago la siguiente consulta:
Tengo tres tablas: `tabla_productos`, `tabla_sucprod` y `tabla_kardex` con los siguientes valores.

```
tabla_producto
COD_PROD  | ...
PROD1     |  
PROD2     | 
PROD3     |



tabla_sucprod
COD_SUCPROD  | SUCURSAL_fk | PRODUCTO_fk
SUC1-PROD1   | SUC1        | PROD1        
SUC1-PROD2   | SUC1        | PROD2       
SUC1-PROD3   | SUC1        | PROD3       
SUC2-PROD1   | SUC2        | PROD1  
SUC2-PROD2   | SUC2        | PROD2 



tabla_kardex
CODKARDEX| SUCPROD_FK | UNIDADES | UND_TOTAL 
1        | SUC1-PROD1 | 3        | 3
2        | SUC1-PROD2 | 10       | 10
3        | SUC1-PROD3 | 15       | 15
4        | SUC2-PROD1 | 1        | 1
5        | SUC2-PROD2 | 5        | 5
6        | SUC1-PROD1 | 6        | 9
7        | SUC1-PROD1 | 80       | 89
8        | SUC1-PROD2 | 12       | 22
9        | SUC2-PROD1 | 5        | 6
```

Requiero obtener el ultimo registro del campo `unidad_total` de cada producto en la `tabla_kardex`, ya que a medida que van ingresando productos se suman las unidades en el campo (`und_total`) y se crea un nuevo registro en la `tabla_kardex`.

Resultado esperado:

```
CODK| SUCPROD_FK | UND_TOTAL |
7   | SUC1-PROD1 | 89        |
8   | SUC1-PROD2 | 22        |
3   | SUC1-PROD3 | 15        |
9   | SUC2-PROD1 | 6         |
5   | SUC2-PROD2 | 5         |
```

Lo que hice es: Relacionar la `tabla_producto` con `tabla_sucprod` y `tabla_kardex`, como solo necesito obtener un resultado por producto de la `tabla_kardex` utilicé la sentencia `GROUP_BY` a la `tabla_producto.cod_prod` pero al hacer esta sentencia obtengo solo el primer registro relacionado y no así el último registro requerido. También agregué un `ORDER_BY` a `tabla_kardex.sucprod_fk`.

PD: No requiero obtener el resultado mayor de `UND_TOTAL` sino el último por cada producto.

```
SELECT 
    codk,
    sucprod_fk,
    und_total
FROM
    kardex
    INNER JOIN sucprod ON kardex.sucprod_fk = sucprod.sucprod_fk
    INNER JOIN producto ON sucprod.prod_fk = producto.cod_prod
GROUP BY
    producto.cod_prod 
ORDER BY
    kardex.sucprod_fk DESC
```

Averigüé: `RANK()`, `DENSE_RANK()`, `ROW_NUMBER()` y `HAVING` pero no logro aplicarlo.

Comment: Yo te sugiero que agreges un nuevo campo de fecha y a base a eso, obtengas lo que necesitas

Answer (score 0):

Debes obtener siempre el último valor para cada `sucprod_fk`, como se desconoce (porque puede cambiar con cada transacción), lo mejor es ordenarlos y obtener el Last value o el First value. Esta aproximación es usando una Window Function para asignar el id #1 siempre al último registro.

```
with x as (
    select codk,
       sucprod_fk,
       unidades,
       und_total,
       row_number() over (partition by sucprod_fk order by codk desc) as last

from kardex
)

select * from x where last = 1
```

Dentro de la vista CTE llamada x se encapsula la lógica que ordenará los elementos por el id de sucprod. Después se filtra para obtener siempre el más reciente de acuerdo con el codk. Como el orden es descendente, siempre tendrás en primer lugar el último, así se podrá filtrar de forma fácil :) .

```
+----+----------+--------+---------+----+
|codk|sucprod_fk|unidades|und_total|last|
+----+----------+--------+---------+----+
|7   |SUC1-PROD1|80      |89       |1   |
|8   |SUC1-PROD2|12      |22       |1   |
|3   |SUC1-PROD3|15      |15       |1   |
|9   |SUC2-PROD1|5       |6        |1   |
|5   |SUC2-PROD2|5       |5        |1   |
+----+----------+--------+---------+----+
```

Comment: MUCHAS GRACIAS!! esto me funciono perfectamente.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esta solución. Cree la estructura que mencionas para evitar confusiones:

```
CREATE TABLE tabla_kardex (
  codkardex integer,
  sucprod_fk varchar,
  unidades integer,
  und_total integer,
  CONSTRAINT tabla_kardexs_pk PRIMARY KEY (codkardex)
)

INSERT INTO tabla_kardex (codkardex,sucprod_fk,unidades,und_total)
VALUES (1,'SUC1-PROD1',3 ,3),
(2,'SUC1-PROD2',10,10),
(3,'SUC1-PROD3',15,15),
(4,'SUC2-PROD1',1 ,1),
(5,'SUC2-PROD2',5 ,5),
(6,'SUC1-PROD1',6 ,9),
(7,'SUC1-PROD1',80,89),
(8,'SUC1-PROD2',12,22),
(9,'SUC2-PROD1',5 ,6);
```

Y esta es la solución:

```
select distinct on (sucprod_fk)
     sucprod_fk,
     codkardex,
     und_total
from tabla_kardex
order by sucprod_fk,codkardex desc;
```